# Watermark overlay fluctuate in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading, watermark, dimensions

When I use to do watermark overlay in codeigniter, the size of watermark image comes different for different dimension images. Following code is using for watermarking.

```
function do_upload_img()
{
    if(isset($_FILES['portfolioimg']['size']) != 0){
       $name_array = array();
       $files = $_FILES;
       $cpt = count($_FILES['portfolioimg']['name']);

       // $config['source_image'] = ''; //get original image
       $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
       $config['wm_overlay_path'] = './assets/img/watermark.png';
       $config['quality'] = 50;
       $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
       $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
       // $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

       for($i=0; $i<=$cpt-1; $i++)
       {           
           $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['portfolioimg']['name'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['portfolioimg']['type'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['portfolioimg']['tmp_name'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['portfolioimg']['error'][$i];
           $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['portfolioimg']['size'][$i];    

           $imgnam = rand(10,1000000);
           $ext = pathinfo($files['portfolioimg']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
           if($this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options($imgnam))){
               $data = $this->upload->do_upload();
               $config['source_image'] = './assets/portfolio_img/' . 'Rookie_'.$imgnam.'.'.$ext;
               $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
               $this->image_lib->watermark(); 
               $name_array[] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
           } else {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('falsemsg','Only jpg, jpeg, png files are allowed to be uploaded.');
           }

       } 
       return $name_array;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
}


private function set_upload_options($imgnam)
{   
     //upload an image options
     $config = array();
     $config['upload_path']   = './assets/portfolio_img/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
     $config['max_size']      = '0';
     $config['overwrite']     = true;
     $config['file_name']     = 'Rookie_'.$imgnam;

     return $config;
 }
```

So please help me to fix this issue. I want the watermark image should be same size for all the images that I'm going to upload.

These are images I uploaded:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx68t.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZO8V.jpg)

Thanks in advance :)